# How do I make a loop off of this code for iMacros?

Tags: firefox, macros, firefox-addon, imacros

So this is my code right now and as you can see this clearly is possible using a loop. The number between the bracket is what I want to change.

How do I make a loop from here since I want to go to like 100 or higher instead of having to copy and paste and change the value?

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type(1) MODIFIERS=shift
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type(2) MODIFIERS=shift
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type(3) MODIFIERS=shift
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type(4) MODIFIERS=shift
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type(5) MODIFIERS=shift
```

This is my new code I wrote for Javascript.

```
var test;

test ="CODE:";
test +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+"\n";
test +="URL GOTO=http://tppcrpg.net/create_trade.php?id=1 "+"\n";
test +="EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type({{!loop}}) MODIFIERS=shift"

for (var i = 1; i < 10 ; i++)
{
test +="EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type" + ({{String(i)}}) + "MODIFIERS=shift"
}

iimPlay(test)
iimPlay("myMacro.iim")
```

Just wondering how to program it so that it can run with me going to the link and selecting from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
var test;

test ="CODE:";
test +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+"\n";
test +="URL GOTO=http://tppcrpg.net/create_trade.php?id=1 "+"\n";
test +="EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type{{n}) MODIFIERS=shift"

for (var i = 1; i < 10 ; i++)
{

iimSet("n",i)
iimPlay(test)
iimPlay("myMacro.iim")

}
```

Comment: Thanks this code did run successfully without any Syntax errors. However, I have some logic errors and here I'll show you an image of this logic problem. http://imgur.com/VE1DVn6. What I'm really trying to do is make it look like this instead: http://imgur.com/rXTx5Qq . Basically in order to select multiple, I have to hold the CTRL KEY and select the item on the list. If I'm not clear enough feel free to ask. Thanks for the try. :)

Comment: This issue is unknown to me. I guess you will have to select them one by one. Sometimes it helps to view page source and views those options you want to be clicked.

Comment: According to this screenshot, it says on the top of the instructions to select multiple things on the list. I can try emailing you the whole source code if needed. You basically select them one by one, which is why a loop helps. http://imgur.com/aanAE1J

Comment: So you selected all of them instad of one by one. Like 1 - 1,2 - 1,2,3 - 1,2,3,4 and so on ? Did you try to deselect and then select another one. Can you send me imacros wiki link where you find this about modifiers ?

Comment: http://wiki.imacros.net/DirectScreen_Technology This link shows the wiki for modifiers (see the Key section). And yeah each time I run the Javascript, I want to select the whole loop but I want to only select 1 item on the modifier list every time I play the iim file.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=#CP>OPTION:nth-of-type({{!loop}}) MODIFIERS=shift
```

Comment: Thanks I tested it and it worked. I'm wondering how do I set it so that I can do other tasks besides selecting the "selector lists"? I would like to do like a "go to link" so that I can select it 100 times.

Comment: Also, I created a new macro and typed in 1 line iimPlay("myMacro.iim") function but it won't run. It gives me this error:  SyntaxError: can not parse macro line: iimPlay("myMacro.iim") (Error code: -910)

Comment: Is the myMacro.iim alongside #Current.iim ? If not then place it there and try again. Also what is this MODIFIERS=shift part ? Where can I read about it?

Comment: @IceD I edited my question and I added the Javascript code I tested out. It didn't run but is there a way I can fix that? The shift part is used in Firefox so that it can select from a list multiple elements.